# Handshaking lemma with 3 people?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-theory, vertices, undirected-graph

Handshaking lemma states in an undirected graph an even number of vertices must have odd degree.

However 3 people shaking hands with each other, 6 hand shakes, or two a each. So there are no vertices with odd degree.

Does the handshaking lemma hold true because 0 is even and there are zero vertices of odd degree?

I'm not doubting the lemma is true, just thinking I'm missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the handshaking lemma hold true because 0 is even and there are
>   zero vertices of odd degree?

Yes. Since all 3 vertices are of even-degree, so there are zero vertices of odd-degree.

You're absolutely correct. Same is the case when people = 1.

Comment: Thank you, I saw your typo, but I made a similar typo when I posted my question.

Comment: @user1768079 - I hope it is clear to you logically as well. *`An even number of people must have shaken an odd number of other people's hands`* --- which can be verified thinking logically too.

Comment: It was clear to me, I just wasn't sure if I was missing something in cases like this. I thought maybe I was misunderstanding the definition of something. All of the examples I was given showed graphs without a cycle that included every vertex or had some other condition that made it different from a graph with odd number of vertices all of equal, even degrees.

Comment: @user1768079 - It is good that you decided to ask it here. It shows you're inquisitive. Keep it up! Good Luck.